# ASP.NET MVC role-based access user and admin using identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application using `Identity` class I am facing a problem in role-based authentication: how to display admin to admin related view and user to user related view?

Here is what I tried

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBtoC.png)

Comment: Please **DO NOT** post a screenshot of your code - post the **code itself** and properly format it !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@inject SignInManager<AspNetMvcCore.Services.Models.User> SignInManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
}

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("User"))
{
}
```

and add roles

```
public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

       public HomeController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
       {
           _roleManager = roleManager;

       }

       [HttpGet]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
       {

         IdentityResult createUserRole = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("User"));
         IdentityResult createAdminRole = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));           
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use the AuthorizeAttribute (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.0#adding-role-checks).

```
[Authorize(Roles = "HRManager,Finance")]
public class SalaryController : Controller
{
}
```

You can also apply the AuthorizeAttribute on controller methods.

Don't forget the UseAuthorization middleware.